# Ethernet port not working

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, port, cable

I have an ethernet port which used to work before. The port is connected to a switch, and the switch is connected to the router. It suddenly stopped working, as in any device connected to the port will not pick up the connection.

I tested with a basic network cable connecter, the main part of the tester was connected to the cable that's connected to the port, and the other part was connected to the cable that's normally connected to the switch. The test light orders were as follows.

Main part  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

other part 3 6 1 4 5 2 7 8

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: The way in which you use the word "_connected_" makes your question unclear... to clarify, the ethernet port with the issue is one of the switch's ports?  If so, is it a dumb switch or a managed/smart switch _(if the latter, have you verified it's attached to a vlan interface?)_  Ethernet ports can be fried by an electrical surge _(for example, if a cable modem experiences a surge on the RG6 cable, that can fry the WAN port on a router)_, and if it is fried, there's no saving that port; if it's a smart/managed switch, remove the port from the vlan, else replace if needing that port.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, I had to swap the orange and green wires with one another in the port connection.